# onDataSetChanged() not called after the notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget

I have an application that contains a widget with a listview that includes checkboxes. When a checkbox is clicked, the widget is updated. This functionality works well, but I have observed that if I start the app and then quickly shut it down, the widget will not be updated. It seems that the onDataSetChanged function is not being called in this scenario. However, all click events in the widget, including those of the checkboxes, work well.

Can anyone help me identify the problem and suggest a solution?

I have googled and searched on stackoverflow and someone said it's the problem of the kind of Phone. That really makes me confused cuz I tested three phones and they all worked not well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.